# Using "was" even though it still is the case

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Is it okay to say was even though it still is the case?

> He had his xray this morning and it was normal.
>
> He had his xray this morning and it’s normal.

Comment: Related: [What is the rule of tense backshifting in a subordinate clause following a past form modal verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70008/) and [The curious case of backshifting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69088/) Basically, native Anglophones aren't all that interested in accurately reflecting contextually obvious aspects such as past / present / future through verb *tense*. We like things to be simple, and structurally balanced, so it's quite natural to echo Past ***had*** with Past ***was*** in such contexts, *regardless* of "exact meaning".

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to say "it was normal".  You are reporting the interpretation of the x-ray photograph made by the doctor, and that interpretation happened in the past.

You could use the present tense, and that would be common if the photograph was available to show

> He had an x-ray this morning. Here is the photograph. Fortunately, everything is normal.

Comment: I find it interesting that we'd be *very* unlikely to use ***was*** in your example - but that's entirely because it clashes so badly with preceding ***Here is...*** It would be fine with *I've **just seen** the photograph. Fortunately, everything **was** normal* - even though we often say Present Perfect implies "strong connection to time of speaking", that's not enough to prevent us using ***was*** there (though ***is*** would be equally natural).

Comment: (There is of course no *need* for contextual props such as having the xray itself to hand to justify using present tense. It's effectively just an optional stylistic device that can be used to introduce "immediacy" to the statement.)