# Talking about a past habit in a story narration

Tags: tense, past-tense

I was watching a comedy show; the comedian was talking about going on a trip with his dad and he said "I was sharing a hotel room with my dad. I knew he snored.".

Is it right to use simple past tense "snored" when talking about someone else's habit in a story?

Comment: Obviously it's "right", or the comedian wouldn't have said it. Most stand-up comics are *very* particular about exactly what they say and how they say it. Unlike sports commentators who "shoot from the lip" and often misspeak, stand-up comics usually spend a lot of time fine-honing their [shtick.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtick) So learn English from comics and JK Rowling, not sports commentators and Dickens!

Comment: But is there some specific *reason* you think there's something "odd" about the cited usage? It looks perfectly ordinary to me as a native speaker.

Comment: Yes, I have a native teacher that said it should be present simple instead of past simple like: "I knew he snores". This might've happened because of my miscommunication. I'll ask they again.

Comment: There have been many threads on this forum about [backshifting of tenses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69088/the-curious-case-of-backshifting) - when you report speech (or in this case, knowledge) in the past about something that is still true. Basically, you can use either past or present tense.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities here. What seems most likely to me is that the story is about events in the past and so  the verbs "knew" and "scored" are both in the past because that is when the actions occurred. Or this might be a case of backshifted speech as a comment suggests. In either case the usage is fine and no change is needed.